# Randomly selecting a key based on the frequency of a value

Tags: java, hashmap, frequency-analysis

I have the following Hashmap:

```
Map <Country, List<City>> map = new HashMap<Country, List<City>>();
```

I want to pick a group of countries at random, with the following condition: Countries with a lower number of cities should have a higher probability of being selected.

To tackle this I thought I would create the following map:

```
Map <Country, Integer> map = new HashMap<Country, Integer>();
```

Where the integer represents the size of `List<City>`.

This is so that I can then sort the `Map` based on the Integer value and then select countries with low Integer values.

But it seems like I am doing this in a very long way, plus it is not very random. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this problem efficiently?

Comment: How about you just use a `TreeMap` with your own `Comparator` which will automatically sort the values based on size?

Comment: What are this T and List you're referring to? Please re-read your post from our point of view (people who haven't seen your code because you haven't posted any), and edit it so that everything is crystal-clear.

Comment: the map get/put takes O(1) roughly speaking, so your idea with the additional map to keep the value frequency doesn't look "a very long way"

Comment: @musical_coder I edited the question, i hope it makes more sense now

Comment: @RegUser "So the lower the size of List<City> the more likely it is to be selected." what does this mean?  Your question is a bit obtuse cause you never explain what you're doing.  Are you just looking for the country with the lowest city count?  The above quote indicates maybe not but it's unclear.

Comment: Much better! Your question is way more clear now. Undoing my downvote. Please keep clarity in mind for future questions you post.

Comment: @Taylor I want to pick a group of Countries with the lowest number of cities. Sorry my question is unclear, I have tried to make it clearer.

Comment: @CyrilDeba how do you suggest I should sort the Map based on the integers?

Comment: The time complexity of your approach is the same. Space is not a problem with an earthly number of countries. It's true there /could/ be something slightly more elegant, but your idea will work clearly and well - as long as the maps aren't called by the same name.

Comment: @clwhisk how would I randomly pick a country based on the integer value? So the higher the integer the more likely it is to be selected? I can pick countries with the lowest number of cities but this is not very random.

Comment: You need to specify the probability distribution you want. The simplest is each country's chance proportional to 1 / its cities. Getting random values is easy (java.util.Random), but it's tricker selecting a group.

Comment: @RegUser you may use Comparator to sort by value the Map and get the highest one

Comment: @clwhisk I do have probabilities in this form {0.0, 0.346, 0.70} but in some cases the number of cities = 0. So I cannot inverse. Is there a work around? how can you weight the random selection based on the probabilities?

Comment: Proportional to `1/numcities + a`, then, but it's really none of my business what distribution of chances you want. I would use Random.nextDouble() for a number 0-1. The math/coding should be straightforward enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a parallel here with the technique used in genetic algorithm called [the roulette wheel selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection).

It is pretty simple to implement :

1. Create an array of countries whom size is the total of integer for all the countries
2. Put each country N times in the array where N is the number of cities
3. Randomly select a value in the array

The countries will be picked with a probability equal to their number of cities

EDIT : if the number of cities is very large, you can normalize the numbers by dividing by the lowest cities count, so that each country remains present in the table.

Comment: This allows countries with a higher number of cities a higher probability of being selected. I would like the exact opposite, so that countries with a lower number of cities will have a high probability of being selected.

Comment: Maybe invert the numbers and then multiply by 100? because you will end up with a number that is lower than 1?

Comment: I just realised that is not a good idea because some of my values = 0 and you cannot divide by 0. So is there another way to do that does not involve inverting)?

Comment: Inverting and multiplying is the good solution to invert the process. Regarding zero values, how does it changes if you add 1 to all the values ?

Comment: Btw if the difference between the highest and lowest value is too large and leads to an almost no selection of low probability countries, do not hesitate to use the log or sqrt function to reduce the interval.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to pick a group of countries with the lowest number of Cities.

Then you want a `List` of countries in order or number of cities.  Why not create a `Country` class that contains a `List` of cities

```
public class Country{
   private final List<String> cityNames = new ArrayList<String>();
   private String name;
   public Country(String n) { name = n; }
   public void addCity(String name){ 
       cityNames.add(name);   // omitting validation
   }
   public List<String> getCityNames(){
       List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
       newList.addAll(cityNames);
       return newList;
   }
   public int numberOfCities(){ 
       return cityNames.size(); 
   }

   public String getName() { return name; }

   @Override
   public String toString(){
      return name + ": Number of Cities = " + cityNames.size();
   }
}
```

Now you can sort a list of countries based on city count like this

```
... // inside some method

        Collections.sort(countries, new Comparator<Country>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Country o1, Country o2) {
            if(o1.numberOfCities() < o2.numberOfCities()){
                return -1;
            }
            if(o1.numberOfCities() > o2.numberOfCities()){
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

I just tested this with the following (NOTE: I added a "toString()" method to Country)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Country usa = new Country("USA");
    Country canada = new Country("Canada");
    Country brazil = new Country("Brazil");
    usa.addCity("Lansing");
    usa.addCity("New York");
    usa.addCity("Los Angeles");
    usa.addCity("Houston");

    canada.addCity("Toronto");

    canada.addCity("Niagra");

    brazil.addCity("Vila Velha");
    brazil.addCity("Rio");
    brazil.addCity("Barbacena");

    List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();
    countries.add(usa);
    countries.add(brazil);
    countries.add(canada);
    System.out.println("\n\nAfter Sorting...");
    it = countries.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
    Collections.sort(countries, new Comparator<Country>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Country o1, Country o2) {
            if(o1.numberOfCities() < o2.numberOfCities()){
                return -1;
            }
            if(o1.numberOfCities() > o2.numberOfCities()){
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });

    System.out.println("\n\nAfter Sorting...");
    it = countries.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }

}
```

And the output

```
 Before sorting....
 USA: Number of Cities = 4
 Brazil: Number of Cities = 3
 Canada: Number of Cities = 2


 After Sorting...
 Canada: Number of Cities = 2
 Brazil: Number of Cities = 3
 USA: Number of Cities = 4
```

Comment: "A Map is an *un*sorted collection." depends on the implementation. For instance LinkedHashMap maintains an insertion order.

Comment: After sorting do you just use Math.Random where if the number if < 0.8 then you pick a random index from the first 50% and if it is > 0.8 you use a random index from the last 50%?

Comment: @RegUser: If that works for you, sure.  There are many choices.  But having a sorted list allows you to focus on the index instead of the city size.

Comment: @MadConan I have implemented this but I'm not allowed to iterate through the collection.. I need to sample data. Is there an effective way of sampling? Thanks

Comment: @RegUser:  I'm not sure what you mean.